# How do I create a dynamic regexp with rx?

Tags: regular-expressions, rx

I want to use `rx` to create regular expressions with runtime values.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
(setq strings '("foo" "bar" "baz"))
(eval `(rx symbol-start (or ,@strings) symbol-end))
```

However, I'd rather avoid using `eval`. I've found `rx-to-string`, but it's not clear what FORM I should write:

```
;; error: Unknown rx form `symbol-start
(rx-to-string '(symbol-start (or ,@strings) symbol-end))
```

How do I build an `rx` expression at runtime?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`rx-to-string` takes a regexp form as an argument. The syntax is the same as the argument of `rx`.

```
(rx-to-string '(or "foo" "bar"))
"\\(?:\\(?:bar\\|foo\\)\\)"
```

What you tried passing is not a regexp form, but a list of regexp forms. Since what you mean is the sequence of regular expressions `symbol-start` followed by one of a bunch of strings followed by `symbol-end`, you need to lead with the sequence operator `sequence` (which can be abbreviated to `seq` or `:`, or weirdly even `and`).

```
(rx-to-string `(: symbol-start (or ,@strings) symbol-end))
"\\(?:\\_<\\(?:ba[rz]\\|foo\\)\\_>\\)"
```

`rx` is in fact a tiny wrapper around `rx-to-string` that operates at compile time because it's a macro. What makes this confusing is that if you pass multiple arguments to `rx`, there is an implicit `sequence` operator. The documentation of `rx` could stand to be clarified.

```
(rx (: symbol-start (or "foo" "bar" "baz") symbol-end))
"\\_<\\(?:ba[rz]\\|foo\\)\\_>"
(rx symbol-start (or "foo" "bar" "baz") symbol-end)
"\\_<\\(?:ba[rz]\\|foo\\)\\_>"
```

Comment: "you pass multiple arguments to rx, there is an implicit sequence operator" -- aha! That's the main gotcha here. Thanks!